# Can I get the Tridion item XML through the CoreServiceClient?

Tags: core-service

Is is possible to retrieve Tridion item XML though the core service client in Tridion?

In TOM.NET this would be `Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.ToXml()`.

I am not looking for the Core Service Client's `Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.ComponentData.Content`. This is useful indeed but only gives the XML representation of the component fields.

Comment: Great question Jan.  I also recently wanted to do the same thing but could not find the way to do it with one call.  There is also the .Info class as part of the ComponentData, but I didn't see a method to put that info in the original XML.

Comment: Why would you want to do it?

Comment: In this case I wanted to inspect a multimedia components namespace. As a multi media component does not have a XML content like a text component I thought having a look at the raw item xml might be helpful.

Comment: FWIW - you might try this: $core.Read($core.Read("tcm:3-4371",$null).Schema.IdRef,$null).NamespaceURI

Answer (score 10):

If you *really* want the XML you can get it. Basically, the CoreService response is actually in XML, and the WCF client will serialize/deserialize from/to XML, and what you can do is tell WCF that you want the XML for a given object.

Like this. (originally posted [here](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GettingTridionXmlFromCoreService))

```
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("wsHttp_2011");
ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
IdentifiableObjectData tridionObject = client.Read("tcm:0-12-1", readOptions);
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(tridionObject.GetType()); 
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    dcs.WriteObject(ms, tridionObject);
    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(ms);
    Console.Write(document.OuterXml);
}
```

This will return R6 XML, it's not your father's R5 XML anymore, so you may have to play around with it for a while.

Comment: Cool, so on the soap request response level the core service uses R6 XML and its the core service client dll hiding that. R6 xml is fine, I never asked for R5 specifically.

Comment: I think it's a level deeper than the CS client dll, it is a "native WCF" transformation.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't overlooked anything; there is no easy way to get the "R5 XML". There's a separate assembly used to create that XML for the CME, but even that is likely to be phased out in the upcoming releases. Managed objects are usually much easier to work with.

You can always serialize objects using the standard .NET serializers if you just want it in XML (or JSON) - for transportation purposes for example.

Comment: True, the thing is that Tridion doesn't store items in XML. It was used a lot in the old Business Connector days, but since then a lot of effort was spent to move away from it.

Comment: For transportation, migration the xml would be easier to handle than serialized objects I think. Good to know that Tridion is moving away from it though.

Comment: The information in question - i.e. the parts of a component *other* than the content, were not generally stored as XML even going back quite some versions. The "R5 XML" was generated dynamically.