# What is the best approach to read the "Component Source" from the CMS

Tags: 2011, 2009, schema, c#, component

Want to read the Component Source form the Tridion CMS and want to store each component source on the CMS server or local machine

How should proceed with it still don't have clear idea which version of Tridion using it may be 2009, 2011 SP1.

Can anyone give me the best approach to proceed.

Comment: For 2011 SP1, visit this link http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5268/can-i-get-the-tridion-item-xml-through-the-coreserviceclient

Answer (score 1):

Condidering the versions of Tridion you want to work with I would recommend the TOM API:

```
var TDSE = WScript.CreateObject("TDS.TDSE");
var content = TDSE.GetObject("tcm:1-2", 1).GetXml(96);
```

This is JScript code but you can use VBScript, PowerShell, .Net or anything else that does COM interop...